# What happened to the stackexchange network?

Tags: bug, status-completed

A few minutes ago the whole SE network seemed to be inaccessable, and on some pages I still get the same errors, either a 404 error:

[image]

or the following:

[image]

(***I get these errors when I visit area51, Islam.SE, and Stackexchange.com (except for this meta)***)

Comment: Uh oh, [#SnowOps](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23SnowOps) was uncovered! Code red, abort, abort!

Comment: english.se, too. (back now though)

Comment: Looks like it works again

Comment: There were some issues on chat, too.

Comment: https://twitter.com/GABeech/status/560570053448302592

Comment: Chat is still mostly broken for me...

Comment: I'm back onto chat, though I had to refresh the pages about 6 times.

Comment: why is this offtopic?

Comment: @Fabián read the description in the notice: "The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. **Changes to the system** or to the circumstances affecting the asker **have rendered it obsolete**. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question." I've **emphasized** the relevant portions, though this does make it seem like this close reason could be applied to *any* [tag:status-completed] bug...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [image]